# Switch a drop down select from disabled to enabled by clicking "edit"

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down select input field with two options already disabled. I'm trying the switch the select from disabled to abled when the user clicks the "edit" link.

```
<select disabled> 
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
<span class="hyperlink" onclick ="languageDropBox();">Edit</span>   


function languageDropBox(){
var html = '<select><option value="English">English</option><option value="Spanish">Spanish</option></select>';
}
```

Comment: Answered this question and the one you commented on. Take a look and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You do this by removing attribute 'disabled'.

```
$('select').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simply process, however a little confusing in that the disabled property is so stand alone.

There are 2 simple ways to do this using jQuery. With one, [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/), you simply remove the attribute, with nothing more. Like so:

```
$('select').removeAttr('disabled');
```

With the other, [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), you use a Boolean to establish if it is "on" or "off". This could be useful if you wanted to toggle it. For instance, in the following, clicking edit will "*turn off*" the disabled, while selecting an option will "*turn on*" the disabled attribute:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
});

$('.hyperlink').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).prev('select').prop('disabled', false)
});
```

## Working Example

---

As it stands, it looks like you may be a little confused on how to keep up with "who" gets "what" command. This is also quite easy. One simple method is to assign `id` attribute to each element. Then it becomes as simple as:

```
<select id="bob">...</select>
...
$("#bob").doSomething
```

Here, I simply use the CSS selector for selecting an elment by ID. In this case, for the id "bob", I use `#bob` in my jQuery selector, (thats this part `$('selector goes here')`).

There is a set back to using `id`. You can only have one unique ID pure element. To have more than one, not only becomes confusing, only the first is ever read by the JavaScript. Thus, I like to use "name-spacing" with "class names". Name-spacing simply means giving an individual name to start something with that keeps it classed apart from others. So as you'll see in my js example, the "name-space" I used for my edit button is "edit". Then I follow with what it edits. in the case, select boxes. So I end up with a class name of `edit-select` which can be used to edit event's on ALL elements having that name space.

Thus `$('.edit-select').doStuff` will cause an event to be set for ALL elements having that name space. So I could easily expand on the html their, and, as long as disablled select is **before** (since I used `prev`, see links below), it will effect only that select.

#### Example

---

### Links to look @:

- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [.removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/)
- [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [.prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [.on/.live](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [jQuery callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/)
- [***How jQuery works***](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a better approach

**HTML:**

```
<select disabled> 
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
<button class="hyperlink">Edit</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".hyperlink").click(function(){
    $("select").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/JKw5K/

**Edit:**

IF you have more than one select dropdown, just add a class name to each one of them

***Example:***

```
<select class="dropdown1">
     <option>This is # 1</option>
     <option>This is # 2</option>
     <option>This is # 3</option>
</select>

<select class="dropdown2">
     <option>This is # 1</option>
     <option>This is # 2</option>
     <option>This is # 3</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $(".hyperlink").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown1").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

or

```
$(".hyperlink").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown2").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

or add a second button to enable the second dropdown

**HTML:**

```
<button class="hyperlink2">Edit Second Dropdown</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $(".hyperlink").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown1").prop("disabled", false);
});

$(".hyperlink2").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown2").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Working Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/2DE5z/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select disabled> 
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
<span class="hyperlink" onclick ="languageDropBox();">Edit</span>   


function languageDropBox(){
 $("select").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following .removerAttr();

$('select').removeAttr('disabled');